# problems with IEEEtran.bst

Tags: bibtex, ieeetran

I am using MiKTeX and the IEEEtran package is installed for my thesis paper.  Does anyone have any idea of what the problem could be? Seems like it cannot find the bib file.

I moved the \bibliographystyle {IEEEtran} to the end of the document, right above the call to the bibliography call statement, (as shown below).

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}

\bibliography{IEEEabrv/mybib2} 

\end{document}
```

partial error message:

```
Process started

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.6600 64-bit)
The top-level auxiliary file: Chapters 1-3.aux
The style file: IEEEtran.bst I couldn't open database file IEEEabrv/mybib2.bib ---line 208 of file Chapters 1-3.aux : \bibdata{IEEEabrv/mybib2 : }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command I found no database files---while reading file Chapters 1-3.aux Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "SSEL" Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Munson"
```

Comment: It says it can't find `IEEEabrv/mybib2.bib ` do you have such a file?

Comment: The problem is *not* with the file `IEEEtran.bst`. Rather, it is that BibTeX cannot find the bib file `mybib2.bib`. Is it located in the subdirectory `IEEEabrv`, or is it maybe somewhere else?

Comment: Thank you for helping, that is correct, I figured it out yesterday.  I have two problems, one is the syntax and two, the directory was not listed for the bibtex file.
Thanks everyone.